# check if value in textbox is valid

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, textbox, prism

I have a textbox with a validator that permits only integer values. How do I check if text in my textbox represents a correct integer value without checking the text itself?

I am using Prism MVVM so I would like to hear some solution like "bind a validator property to your viewmodel/model code", but a generic WPF solution is also fine.

The problem is that I can't get the incorrect value in my model / viewmodel. If the value is incorrect, then the underlying binded property doesn't get set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IDataErrorInfo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx), or [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). The [Data Annotations Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) project contains an `Integer` attribute.

Comment: +1 for `IDataErrorInfo`. Even if you use `DataAnnotations`, you should still use `IDataErrorInfo` as well since WPF is built to work with it.

Comment: I don't see how I can use IDataErrorInfo. I can't get the incorrect value in my model or viewmodel, I can see only the correct value. If current value is incorrect, then it won't get passed to the viewmodel/model.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157894/poco-validation-on-textbox-for-integer-datatype/9161603#9161603. You could use an IValueConverter to always return a valid integer so that your view model is updated.